# How to save data to Firestore database in android using anonymous authentication?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to know, how can I save data to my firestore database anonymously, here is how I do it un authenticated.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference ref = db.collection("mycollection");
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("name", "Hii");
ref.add(data).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> startActivity(new Intent(submit.this, yay.class))).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(submit.this, "Failed to send! Try again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you mean by "anonymously", and how that's different from unauthenticated.

Comment: I meant, by using anonymous authentication

Comment: What am I to do with the FirebaseUser object? Can someone give me code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use anonymous authentication, you don't change the way you write Cloud Firestore code at all.  All you have to do is sign in the user using [Firebase Authentication anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), and the Firestore code will automatically use the anonymous signin credentials.  Your security rules should be prepared for this situation.

Comment: If I copy paste the code from official documentation with some modifications, It always toasts "Authentication failed.". I have set security rules to allow create: if request.auth != null;